# ValueError: model_fn does not take labels, but input_fn returns labels

Tags: tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

I am building model classification using tensorflow-hub, tensorflow-estimators and tensorflow-data.

My train function is returning dataset and the `model_fn` is defined as follows:

```
def train_input_fn():
      return dataset_input_fn(DATASET_TRAIN_PATH)

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params): 
  logging.info("model_fn")
  # module is imported from tf-hub
  return head.create_estimator_spec (features, mode, ...)
```

Very similar to the [code by Damien](https://damienpontifex.com/2018/04/21/image-classification-using-tensorflow-estimators-and-tensorflow-hub-for-transfer-learning/).

The code environment is: Python 2, Google cloud datalab, `tf.version` is 1.12.
The error that is being fired is the `model_fn` is not expecting labels parameter (which is probably generated by `tf-data` dataset). What should be the signature of `model_fn` given that `input_fn` returns a dataset?

Please advise with any idea.

Many thanks,

eilalan

Comment: just hit this myself trying to port a tensorflow hub model

Comment: Hi eilalan, is your issue resolved now? Else, the hyperlink provided by you is not working. Please link it correctly so that we can try to help you. Thanks!